# How to collapse system tray in windows 10 Phone UWP

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm developing windows 10 UWP app. I need to collapse system tray only for Windows 10 Mobile app.

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile system tray? What are you talking about? System tray only occurs in the Desktop version.

Comment: @Herdo I think he/she means the top bar which has the time, battery level, signal ect on it. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: @MikeEason That's what I thought as well. But as long as it is not clarified, no answer will be acceptable.

Comment: your right @Mike Eason. System tray means battery level and mobile signal... in WP8 we use shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" command to collapse tray

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got answer

```
var statusbar = "Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar";
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(statusbar))
{
                //await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ShowAsync();
               await Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add windows phone extention before using above code

Fore more Info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn609832.aspx

Comment: You can use PlatformSpecific.Analyzer from nuget to check for usages of extension SDK API calls, auto-add correctly named guards with IsTypePresent etc.  Really useful

Comment: The link describes how to add the windows mobile extension for UWP.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way that can help you! u should use this code in the public MainPage() class

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

this code hides the status bar and make ur app full screen in phone